# Promise defer in blue bird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I started to use bluebird instead of Q

Currently the code which I use is like following

```
runProcess = function(path) {

    var result = Promise.defer();

    fs.readFileAsync(path)
    .then(function (Content) {
            var parser = new parseFile(Content);
            var adpt = parser.update();
            result.resolve(adpt);
    }, function(error) {
            result.reject(error);
    });
    return result.promise;
}
```

My Question  if there a better way to write it ?

Comment: Beter as in, shorter / more performant / more readable.. ? Please specify.

Comment: @Caramiriel - Shorter and maybe more readable...

Comment: Also, if you make a new promise which you do not need to do here, you should use the ES6 standard way which is `p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {...});`

Comment: one liner `runProcess = path => fs.readFileAsync(path).then(content => (new parseFile(content)).update());` - perfectly readable - maybe not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it can be improved,

step1: stop wrapping promises with promises:

```
runProcess = function(path) {
   return fs.readFileAsync(path)
    .then(function (Content) {
          var parser = new parseFile(Content);
          return parser.update();
    });
}
```

Read about [this Promise anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

In really short ES6 form, it might be:

```
runProcess = path => fs.readFileAsync(path)
                      .then( content => (new parseFile(content )).update())
```

Comment: to go with convention, `content` not `Content` - as I said, convention, but it's a nice convention

Comment: @JaromandaX valid point, updated :)